# Mocking of a function within a function not working in jest with jest.spyOn

Tags: jestjs, mocking, create-react-app

I'm trying to write a test for a function that downloads an Excel file within my React app.

I understand that I need to mock certain functionality, but it doesn't seem to be working according to everything that I have read online.

A basic mock that works is this:

```js
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'
import { xlsxExport } from './functions'

// other code...

test('saveAs', async () => {
    const saveAsSpy = jest.spyOn(FileSaver, 'saveAs')
    FileSaver.saveAs('test')
    expect(saveAsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test')
})
```

The above works: `FileSaver.saveAs` was successfully mocked. However, I am utilising `FileSaver.saveAs` within another function that I wish to test and the mocking does not seem to transfer into that. `functions.ts` and `functions.tests.ts` below.

`functions.ts`:

```js
import { Dictionary } from './interfaces'
import * as ExcelJS from 'exceljs'
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'


export function xlsxExport(data: Dictionary<any>[], fileName?: string, tabName?: string) {
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook()
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(tabName || 'export')

    // Get columns from first item in data
    worksheet.columns = Object.keys(data[0]).map((key: string) => ({ header: key, key: key }))

    // Write each item as a row
    for (const row of data) {
        worksheet.addRow(row)
    }

    // Download the file
    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(function (buffer) {
        const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'applicationi/xlsx' })
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, (fileName || 'excel_export') + '.xlsx')
    })
}
```

`functions.tests.ts`

```js
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'
import { xlsxExport } from './functions'

// ...other code

test('xlsxExport', async () => {
    const saveAsSpy = jest.spyOn(FileSaver, 'saveAs')
    xlsxExport(myArrayOfDicts, 'test_download')
    expect(saveAsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('something, anything')
})
```

Error:

```bash
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createElement')
    at Function.saveAs (C:\dev\pcig-react\node_modules\file-saver\src\FileSaver.js:92:9)
    at C:\dev\pcig-react\src\common\functions.ts:221:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v19.3.0
 FAIL  src/common/functions.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                                                                                              
    Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                              
      at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (node_modules/jest-runner/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:185:21)
```

It is trying to call the non-mocked `FileSaver.saveAs` (line 221 of my file) within `xlsxExport`.

How can I get it to call the mocked version?